# Take too long to respond APACHE2

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I dedicded to migrate from `windows` to `ubuntu`, I'm trying to setup a `local` virtual host`from`apache` but i' getting an error of **the site cannot be reach too long to respond**.

Steps that i've done

- Install Apache2
- Install php7.0
- Install Composer
- Install git
- Create virtual host file to sites-available
- a2ensite the created virtual host
- restart apache2
- edit the /etc/hosts

i also tried to change the ownership of /var/www using `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /var/www` but still can't access my file.

[image]

Comment: Is apache actually running? Is the IP you entered in the hosts file for the name correct? What happens if you go to [http://127.0.0.1](http://127.0.0.1)? [Edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Put `127.0.0.1` in the hosts file, not 55.55.55.55. With your settings the browser tries to access 55.55.55.55 which probably doesn't respond.

Comment: @PerlDuck I tried to chage the 55.55.55.5 to 127.0.0.1 and the directory are shown. But there are one file directory that i can't access which is the `public` it says it `The page isn't working is currently unable to handle this request`. Am i missing something?